# The camera rotates 90 degrees around the x axis when the program is started

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a camera control script. Everything works well, I can look left and right, up and down. But when I run the program, the camera, instead of looking at the center, deviates by 90 degrees around the x axis and I don't know why.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

I've tried to use rotation, localRotation, Angles an so on, but nothing can help me.

Comment: What is following doing? xRotation -= mouseY;  I think it is rotating object 180 degrees.

Comment: @jdweng This line of code is needed in order to use the mouse to rotate the camera around the X axis. I don't really understand how it works and what values it takes, in all videos I've  watched, these lines were added, but they did not have a 90 degree deviation. Link to one of the videos  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc]. But if I set the xRotation variable to -90, then the camera tilts up for the first second, and then starts looking at the center. I don't know how to make the camera immediately look at the center.

Comment: You are setting an angle to a Y distance which does not make any sense.  You need to calculate an angle.  See : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html